# Elasticsearch : Is it possible to not analysed aggregation query on analysed field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have certain document which stores the brand names in analysed form for ex: {"name":"Sam-sung"} {"name":"Motion:Systems"}. There are cases where i would want to aggregation these brands under timestamp.
my query as follow ,

```
{
"size": 0,
 "aggs": {
  "filtered_aggs": {
   "filter": {
     "range": {
      "@timestamp":{
         "gte":"2016-07-18T14:23:41.459Z",
        "lte":"2016-07-18T14:53:10.017Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "execute_time": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brands",
         "size": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

but the return results will be

```
{
...
 "aggregations": {
  "states": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "Sam",
           "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
           "key": "sung",
           "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
           "key": "Motion",
           "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
           "key": "Systems",
           "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but i want to the results is

```
{
...
 "aggregations": {
  "states": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "Sam-sung",
           "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
           "key": "Motion:Systems",
           "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way in which i can make not analysed query on analysed field in elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `not_analyzed` sub-field to your `brands` fields and then aggregate on that field.

```
PUT /index/_mapping/type
{
   "properties": {
      "brands": {
         "type": "string",
         "fields": {
             "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then you need to fully reindex your data in order to populate the new sub-fields `brands.raw`.

Finally, you can change your query to this:

```
POST index/_search
{
"size": 0,
 "aggs": {
  "filtered_aggs": {
   "filter": {
     "range": {
      "@timestamp":{
         "gte":"2016-07-18T14:23:41.459Z",
        "lte":"2016-07-18T14:53:10.017Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "execute_time": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brands.raw",
         "size": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```